# Cannot completely remove zero from the list of python

Tags: python, arraylist

I have two lists

```
x=[0.0, -0.9000000000000199, 2.1499999999999773, 1.799999999999983, -1.5000000000000284, -2.3500000000000227, -3.05000000000004, 2.0999999999999943, 3.9999999999999716, 1.8499999999999943, -4.650000000000006, 11.349999999999994]
y=[-5.750000000000028, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

I use below logic to remove zero completely. But zeroes of y are not completely removed.

```
for i in x:
    if i==0:
        x.remove(i)

for j in y:
    if j==0:
        y.remove(j)
        
print(x)
print(y)
```

I get the output as follows, ie I still have zero in my y list.

```
[-0.9000000000000199, 2.1499999999999773, 1.799999999999983, -1.5000000000000284, -2.3500000000000227, -3.05000000000004, 2.0999999999999943, 3.9999999999999716, 1.8499999999999943, -4.650000000000006, 11.349999999999994]
[-5.750000000000028, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method "remove" only removes the first occurrence of a provided value:

```
def remove(self, *args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
    """
    Remove first occurrence of value.
    
    Raises ValueError if the value is not present.
    """
    pass
```

To remove all values from a list, you can use the following small method:

```
def remove_all_values_from_list(l, val):
    for i in range(l.count(val)):
        l.remove(val)
```

Output:

```
[-0.9000000000000199, 2.1499999999999773, 1.799999999999983, -1.5000000000000284, -2.3500000000000227, -3.05000000000004, 2.0999999999999943, 3.9999999999999716, 1.8499999999999943, -4.650000000000006, 11.349999999999994]
[-5.750000000000028]
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not remove elements from a list while iterating over it. Instead, use a list comprehension:

```
x=[e for e in x if e]
y=[e for e in y if e]
```

Comment: yes, it works. But please provide some explanation on why not remove elements from a list while iterating over it. So that I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with y = [i for i in y if i != 0]